# An advertisement poster for Islam.SE

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

My main intention of writing this post is to encourage users to make adverts for promoting Islam.SE
Please try a hand at making one and post it as an answer here.

Comment: Good ,but I would like suggest edit your question to invite other users designs  , and post your design in answer in the answerbox

Answer (score 2):

**My poster**
I have tried creating a poster. Please leave your comments and feedback on how to improve it.
[image].

It is not yet complete. I have to add a QR code below on the right hand side.

[image]

or this barcode

[image]

Comment: If the original owner of the background image has not given express permission or has not released the image to the public domain, then most probably it *is* copyright infringement.